# How to make realm objects Sendable?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

TLDR: Realm introduces actor isolated realms, but realm objects are not `Sendable`. How is one supposed to use these actor isolated realms then? Or how do I make my Objects Sendable?

---

Realm recently introduced [actor-isolated realms](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/actor-isolated-realm/#std-label-swift-actor-isolated-realm), which we are using with a `@globalActor` that manages Data Persistence in our app, since many different places need to trigger writes / read the data.

Warnings pop up when using this actor with any realm objects being passed around:

> Passing argument of non-sendable type 'any Message' into global actor 'RealmBackgroundActor'-isolated context may introduce data races

I guess this is due to the implementation of our `Message` realm object not being sendable:

```swift
class Message: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable, Codable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: String
    @Persisted var senderUserName: String?
    @Persisted var text: String
    
    convenience init(_id: String = UUID().uuidString, senderUserName: String, text: String) {
           self.init()
            self._id = _id
           self.senderUserName = senderUserName
           self.text = text
       }
}
```

But I cannot make it `Sendable`, because:

> 'Sendable' class 'Message' cannot inherit from another class other than 'NSObject'

**How can one pass data to and from this actor?** I imagine it is quite common to actually use realm data that was read inside an actor also outside the actor, e.g. for updating the UI. Or pass outside objects to the actor to perform writes..

Sidenote: I am very uncertain that I am even using the `@globalActor` the intended way, but I have no idea how else one could ensure there are no data races with the realm data while not having to inject / manage some realm actor manually everywhere.

I had the idea to create for each realm object a sendable swift object, being converted to and from realm objects only inside the actor, but this seems not very clean..

---

Our implementation of the `@globalActor`:

```swift
@globalActor
actor RealmBackgroundActor {
    static var shared = RealmBackgroundActor()
}

@RealmBackgroundActor
class PersistanceService: NSObject {
    
    static let shared: PersistanceService = PersistanceService()
    var realm: Realm?

    func setupRealm() async {
        realm = try? await Realm(actor: RealmBackgroundActor.shared)
    }

    func write(object: Object) {
        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(object, update: .modified)
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

And calling the write function outside of this actor like so:

```swift
await PersistanceService.shared.write(object: object)
```

Comment: I am not clear on the question; Realm writes are thread safe with asyncWrite - this manages realm access in a thread-safe way without requiring you to write specialized code to do it yourself. Also, using (ThreadSafe)[https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/crud/threading/#use-the--threadsafe-wrapper] conforms to Sendable so implementing that would enable the object to be passed between threads. Objects can also be frozen for a read-only version. But what is the use case? It sounds like you want to write data in a thread safe way - doesn't asyncWrite do that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jay . One reason for trying to stick to the new "actor-isolated realms" is that it seems more in-line with the new Swift concurrency language, as realm states "...might want to use an actor-isolated realm if your app uses Swift concurrency language..."

e.g. I only have to open a realm once, on the dedicated actor, and never have to worry about asynchronous calls at all, as long as I stay within this actor. Swift manages the threads.

That said, I am not certain either, just trying to isolate all things realm related into one place, an actor seems very convenient..

Comment: Very often have I ran into errors / crashes in weird places with threads and handling realms / objects, and as realm writes "If your app accesses Realm in an async/await context, mark the code with @MainActor to avoid threading-related crashes." - Now finally with version 10.39.0 I do not have to always use the MainActor / Main thread, but can just have a realm actor that should remove all those crashes and issues. If only I figure out how realm intended to use these actors fully..

Comment: Good info! I agree the usage is kind of vague at this point. I think the messaging is that if you're using await/async, then best bet is to leverage actors. But based on your code and comment above though, it doesn't sound like your using await/async calls so what's the need for the actors? Also, note that - *Realm does not provide Swift async/await support for reading or writing objects* - but they can be thread safely performed using background writes. So why force that pattern? Threading issues are often just a logic issue. So back to the question; what's the need for Sendable?